# Blender 2.8. Simple addon does not work after late december update

Tags: python, scripting

This addon used to work like 10 days ago but with latest build it gives:
`bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation = 'GLOBAL' AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'transform_orientation'`

```
    import bpy

def main(context):


    area = bpy.context.area
    old_type = area.type
    area.type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_center()
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
    bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation = 'GLOBAL'

    area.type = old_type

class actioncenter_origin(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "myops.actioncenter_origin"
    bl_label = "actioncenter_origin"



    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(actioncenter_origin)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(actioncenter_origin)
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.myops.actioncenter_origin()
```

I am complete noob in any sort of coding so this error seems like an unsolvable obstacle to me.

btw orientations pie menu gives the same error

Comment: At a glance try `context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = 'GLOBAL'`  Also since context is passed to main,  replace `bpy.context` with `context`.

Comment: sadly, it gives the same kind of error
context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = 'GLOBAL'
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'transform_orientation'

Comment: installed blender on second machine and now your command works!
now I have to figure out what's happening with my main pc :)
thank you!